# Select Greatest and Least Value from 3 numbers, C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I need the user to input 3 numbers and then have the program select the largest and smallest valued integers. Any advice on what I have wrong? It keeps telling me my Largest integer is 0 and that my smallest integer is 0?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    double largest = 0;
    double smallest = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the First integer: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please enter the Second integer: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Please enter the Third integer: " << endl;
    cin >> c;

    if (b<a>c && b < c)
        largest = a, smallest = b;
    else if (b<a>c && c < b)
        largest = a, smallest = c;
    else if (a<b>c && a < c)
        largest = b, smallest = a;
    else if (a<b>c && c < a)
        largest = b, smallest = c;
    else if (a<c>b && a < b)
        largest = c, smallest = a;
    else if (a<c>b && b < a)
        largest = c, smallest = b; 
    cout << "Largest interger is: " << largest << endl;
    cout << "Smallest interger is: " << smallest << endl;








    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `std::minmax({a, b, c})`

Comment: `b < a > c` does not work like you seem to think it does. Stop trying to do too much all at once.

Comment: Largest -- `std::max(a, std::max(b, c));` --  Smallest -- `std::min(a, std::min(b,c));`.  So are you looking for these type of answers? Don't want to waste time posting an answer and then being told "I can't use that because my teacher / book / whatever hasn't mentioned this".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use a integer object, not a double, as you are working with 3 integers. Also, `a<c` returns a bool so it essentially doing:

```
bool temp = (a<c);
if (temp > b && a<b)
{
    //blah
}
```

instead, try

```
if (a<c && c>b && a<b)
{
    //blah
}
```